# How to correct issues with ABI=64 and ABI=32 while installing a software in Apple M1 Mac

Tags: macos, gmp

I am trying to install a software GAP (https://www.gap-system.org/Releases/) in Apple Macbook Pro with M1 processor and MacOS BigSur. I have successfully unzipped the downloaded file and ./configure worked for me. When I run make then the following error occurs (after some texts):

> configure: error: ABI=64 is not among the following valid choices: 32

Screenshot below:
[image]

So I tried with make ABI=32 and then I get

> configure: error: Oops, mp_limb_t is 64 bits, but the assembler code
> in this configuration expects 32 bits.

Screenshot below:

[image]

Any help will be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem, and got around it using the command `brew install gap-system/gap/gap`. Hope this works for you too.